# If clojure has "require" then why does it have "compile"

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

If `require` takes care of compiling a namespace, then why do we need `compile` in Clojure?

For eg - I can only run the `require` statement instead of running the below two statements:

```
(require '[<name of your namespace>])
(compile '<name of your namespace>)
```

Comment: If you aren't building build tools, you aren't the target audience for `compile`; you don't need it, and shouldn't use it. Joe Clojure Developer shouldn't have any reason to even know `compile` exists.

Comment: BTW -- if there are aspects of this question that my answer doesn't cover, I would appreciate a comment describing what needs to be added. (I would hope you're not asking why ahead-of-time compilation is needed -- that's arguably (1) too broad to be on-topic, and (2) something you could find examples or discussion of by Googling "clojure AOT".

Answer (score 4):

`require` loads a namespace (compiling classes as-necessary) *in-memory*.

`compile` compiles all the classes associated with a namespace *on-disk*.

You should only use `require` unless you know exactly why you're doing anything else.